# Awk (gnu awk) printing comparisons with and without parens have different results

Tags: awk, posix

```
awk 'BEGIN { print 3 > 2 }' a.out
```

Prints nothing

But

```
awk 'BEGIN { print (3 > 2) }' a.out
> 1
```

Prints 1. This repros with any file. Why do the parenthesis have an effect?

GNU AWK 5.1

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

awk has [Redirection](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Redirection.html) like the shell. Check your current directory for a file named "2" -- it will have one line containing the value "3".

With parentheses, you're changing how awk parses the code: giving the expression `3 > 2` higher priority, you're forcing awk to use the relational operator.

This is discussed in the [Precedence](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Precedence.html) chapter of the manual:

> < <= == != > >= >> | |&
>
> > Relational and redirection. The relational operators and the redirections have the same precedence level. Characters such as ‘>’ serve both as relationals and as redirections; the context distinguishes between the two meanings.

See [the index of the gawk manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Index.html#Index_cp_symbol-19) for all uses of `>`

Comment: Thank you glenn! That is surprising. I will accept this answer as soon as SO allows it (4min wait?).

Answer (score 1):

that's why, whenever i need `x greater-than y` compares in `awk`, the safer approach is reverse it and write

```
y < x
```

that way, only `getline` ones need to be watched out for, as opposed to accidentally overwriting files

`'{ print x > y }'`

that happen to have the same name as `y`'s string-value. side note - to best of my understanding, the cleanest way to force numeric compare is probably

```
+y < +x       # doing ( 0+y < 0+x ) is superfluous 
              # in this context since unary `+` has an 
              # implicit `0` to left of it
```